# Dot product as multiplication in armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have a row vector and a column vector and I would like to take their dot product.

```
rowvec v = {1,2,3,4};
vec w = {5,6,7,8};
double a = dot(v,w) // works
double b = v*w // doesn't work
double c = (v*w)(0) // doesn't work
double d = static_cast<vec>(v*w)(0) //works
```

Is it possible to get something that looks like `b`? I would like it for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also use

```
double b = as_scalar(v*w);
```

but that was not really what you wanted ...
Don't think there are any other alternatives available except using mat format for v,w and b. Then you will get a [1x1] matrix for `v*w` and a [4x4] matrix for `w*v`